# Vectorized computation for arrays with different dimensions in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

In scientific computation, a 3D field can be discretized as `F[nx, ny, nz]`, where `nx`, `ny` and `nz` are the numbers of grid points in 3 directions. In every point, assume we have `n-by-n` tensor attached. So for the tensor field, we can use a 5D array to represent `T[n, n, nx, ny, nz]`. The tensor for any point `[i, j, k]` can be selected as `T[:, :, i, j, k]`. If I want to compute sum of off-diagonal elements for each point, I would like to use code

```
import numpy as np
r = np.zeros((nx, ny, nz)) 
for i in range(nx):
    for j in range(ny):
        for k in range(nz):
            r[i,j,k] = np.sum(T[:,:,i,j,k])-np.trace(T[:,:,i,j,k])
```

The result array `r` and tensor field `T` have different dimensions. The calculation of loop over every element is low efficient in Python. Is there any other way to do vectorized or efficient computation for arrays with different dimensions. Or what else data type/structure can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are two different alternatives. The first uses [`ndarray.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) and NumPy [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). The second alternative uses [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).

```
def using_sum(T):
    total = T.sum(axis=1).sum(axis=0)
    m = np.arange(T.shape[0])
    trace = T[m, m].sum(axis=0)
    return total - trace

def using_einsum(T):
    return np.einsum('mnijk->ijk', T) - np.einsum('nnijk->ijk', T)
```

---

The first argument of `np.einsum` specifies the subscripts of the summation.

`'mnijk->ijk'` indicates that `T` has subcripts `mnijk` and only the `ijk` subscripts remain after summation. Therefore the summation is performed over the `m` and `n` subscripts. This makes
`np.einsum('mnijk->ijk', T)[i,j,k]` equal to `np.sum(T[:,:,i,j,k])`, but computes the entire array in one vectorized computation.

Similarly, `'nnijk->ijk'` tells `np.einsum` that `T` has subscripts `nnijk` and again only the `ijk` subscripts survive summation. Therefore the summation is over `n`. Since `n` is repeated, the summation over `n` computes the trace.

I like `np.einsum` because it communicates the intent of the computation
succinctly.  But it's also good to be familiar with how `using_sum` works since
it uses fundamental NumPy operations. It's a good example of how nested loops
can be avoided by using NumPy methods which operate on whole arrays.

---

Here's a [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) comparing the performance of `orig` versus `using_sum` and `using_einsum` as a function of `n`, where `T` is taken to have shape `(10, 10, n, n, n)`:

```
import perfplot
import numpy as np

def orig(T):
    _, _, nx, ny, nz = T.shape
    r = np.zeros((nx, ny, nz)) 
    for i in range(nx):
        for j in range(ny):
            for k in range(nz):
                r[i,j,k] = np.sum(T[:,:,i,j,k])-np.trace(T[:,:,i,j,k])
    return r

def using_einsum(T):
    r = np.einsum('mnijk->ijk', T) - np.einsum('nnijk->ijk', T)
    return r

def using_sum(T):
    total = T.sum(axis=1).sum(axis=0)
    m = np.arange(T.shape[0])
    trace = T[m,m].sum(axis=0)
    return total - trace

def make_T(n):
    return np.random.random((10,10,n,n,n))

perfplot.show(
    setup=make_T,
    kernels=[orig, using_sum, using_einsum],
    n_range=range(2, 80, 3),
    xlabel='n')
```

[image]

`perfplot.show` also checks that the values returned by `orig`, `using_sum` and `using_einsum` are equal.

Comment: Thank you @unutbu and this works well. Here is a follow-up question: Instead of getting the sum of off-diagonal elements, I want to get the maximum eigenvalue of `n-by-n` tensor of each grid point, i.e.  `np.linalg.eig(T(:,:,i,j,k))[0].max()`. Can this function also be used in a vectorization way rather than element-wise loop?

Comment: Notice that [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) say that `eig(a)` expects `a` to be an array of shape `(..., M, M)`. That means that if `a` is of shape `(I, J, K, M, M)` then `vals, vecs = np.linalg.eig(a)` will return `vals` of shape `(I, J, K, M)`. So instead of having a tensor, `T`, of shape `(n, n, nx, ny, nz)` you need a tensor of shape `(nx, ny, nz, n, n)`. So let `T2 = T.transpose(2, 3, 4, 0, 1)`. Then `vals, vecs = np.linalg.eig(T2)` and then `vals.max(axis=-1)` will be an array of shape `(nx, ny, nz)` with the max eigenvalues.